# Setting the frame of an UIView does not work

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have a problem with the frame-property in iOS 7.
I wanna resize some UIViews in the `viewDidLoad`-method of my `UIViewController`, but if I do it like `int screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
[self.leftSideTableView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, screenHeight)];`
the height is set as I want it till the end of the method, but in every other method it is as is has been before!

What's wrong with it or is it just a bug of the compiler or anything else?

Comment: Can you clarify what is wrong? I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: Is it my english or how I explained it? :D
So, the UIView does not change the size! NSLog shows, that there is the right value in it, but it's just till the end of the method! In every other method wich the compiler performs after viewDidLoad it is the old value! :/

Comment: Try setting the frame of the `UIView`s in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear`. The views are not yet laid out in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried viewWillAppear some minutes ago, but it did not work, but viewDidLayoutSubviews is working! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

One has to put view resizing into `-viewDidLayoutSubviews:`! [(documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews)

Placing view frame changes into `-viewWillAppear:` or `-viewDidLoad:` will not work, because the views are not laying out yet!

Comment: Thanks for this. Count on Apple to change their minds on a whim and introduce nasty behavioral changes for extremely basic things that have worked since release 1.0.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work either. viewDidLayoutSubviews does get called, and the frame values change, but the image is still stretched, just as for initWithFrame: in viewWillAppear. Using this code.     CGRect frame=self.navigationItem.titleView.frame;
    frame.size.width=102;
    frame.size.height=44;
    self.navigationItem.titleView.frame=frame;

Comment: Just a note. iOS7 & iOS8 behave differently. on iOS7 changing the frame of a subview triggers layoutSubview, on iOS8 this doesn't happen.

Comment: only this answer was helpful to me

Answer (score 11):

- Check if you are using `autolayout` in your xib file. If you don't want to use `autolayout`, uncheck it in your xib file.
- Change your `self.leftSideTableView` frame in `-viewWillAppear:`.

Answer (score 8):

Check to make sure that auto layout isn't activated in your storyboard file.

To turn it off, look at the inspector in interface builder. Click the icon that looks like a page all the way on the left. In the section "Interface Builder Document" uncheck "Use Auto Layout."

I find it's best to an entire view controller in IB with auto layout, or completely in code. Mixing the two can lead to weird behavior that is hard to debug.

Comment: Man, I banged my head on this for hours (facepalm). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why this might be happening. First of all, you need to make sure that your tableview isn't nil. If you're creating it programmatically, you need to be sure that you're calling alloc/init somewhere before you attempt to set the frame. If `self.leftSideTableView` is an IBOutlet, this can be caused by forgetting to actually link the outlet to the interface object.

Then, second and less likely, you are creating the table view programmatically and initializing it properly, but you forgot to add it as a subview of one of your on screen views.

Comment: The TableView is created in the nib and is linked and now I want to resize it! I'm seeing it on the screen also, and it is filled right, but I'm not able to change the height!

Comment: @MyJBMe Are you using a subclass of UITableViewController?

Comment: No, its a normal UITableView! But @bobnoble just brought the answer! I can not change the size in viewDidLoad - even if i can set shadow - but I can set in viewDidLayoutSubviews! viewWillAppear does not make it too!