# Programatically change size of UIView that is on Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am `attempting to change the size of a UIView` that I have placed in the Storyboard. For some reason the `size does not change` but remains the same as drawn on the Storyboard. I have not hooked up Autolayout so this cannot be the reason it remains the same. My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var courseView: CourseView!  // CourseView is a UIView

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    courseView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)  // This is just to test!
}
```

I have also done the same in `viewDidLoad()` but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `auto layout`? In the superview i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acording to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18273711/839049)

The methods `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidLoad:` have no layout information. Any layout changes made here will be lost when `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` is called later on.

If you are using auto layout you cant change the constraints at any point, but the actual change will happen @`viewDidLayoutSubviews:`

If you are not using auto layout you need to update the layout @`viewDidLayoutSubviews:` or after the view is being presented (@`viewDidAppear:` or by user input)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I find that viewDidLayoutSubviews() actually works better as there is not time lag. If called in viewDidAppear() the original view flashes up and then only does the adapted view get drawn.